# katalon studio open browser once in a while

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, katalon-studio, testautomationfx

This is my code. The username and password variable gets value from excel file. if i execute the code, opens a new browser for each every row ( in excel ). I'am searching for a command or else for open browse one time, at the beginning

WebUI.openBrowser('')

```
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://link.com')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject(' Log In/input_), username)

WebUI.setText(findTestObject(' Log In/input_), password)

WebUI.click(findTestObject(' Log In/button_Login'))

WebUI.delay(5)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Home/a_LOGOUT'))
```

Comment: This cannot be all of your code. I am sure there is a for loop missing. How would you get all the excel rows otherwise? Please share more of the code.

Comment: Its the all code, the katalon automatically get all rows, and loop this code block. 
and the studio read "openBrowser" in every loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it is the problem, but you have some wrong single quotes, try changing your code for this:

```
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://link.com')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject(' Log In/input_'), username)

WebUI.setText(findTestObject(' Log In/input_'), password)

WebUI.click(findTestObject(' Log In/button_Login'))

WebUI.delay(5)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Home/a_LOGOUT'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To open the browser only one time you should make a Test suit and put the "Open browser" test case at first position and after that put the second test case of multiple user log-in.
This will open the browser only one time and Login user as per given Excel data.

In the below image, I show that I make 3 test case in one test suit and username and password is variable:

[image: The below image]